# ¿Cómo puedo crear un diálogo modal simple en angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

¿Cómo puedo crear un diálogo modal simple que contenga algunos enlaces seleccionables?

Cuando cierro la ventana emergente que debo recuperar el valor seleccionado.

Han oído hablar de servicio modal angular pero soy nuevo en esto.

Por eso, ¿alguien podría mostrarme algún ejemplo básico?

Comment: Mírate el [angular-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), quizás te sirva.

Comment: Parece bien.gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Quizas escuchaste hablar de [Angular Modal Service](http://dwmkerr.github.io/angular-modal-service/) por que es liviano y no tiene dependencias, es simplemente un servicio para cajas modales. Pero es mucho menos popular que `ngDialog` (~250 estrallas contra ~2500 en GitHub) aunque tiene las funciones necesarias y también obtienes los resultados por medio de promises.

Aquí te dejo una demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularModalService']);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, ModalService) {

  $scope.mostrarModal = function() {

    // Debes proveer un controlador y una plantilla.
    ModalService.showModal({
      template: '<div class="overlay"/><div class="modal"><input type="text" ng-model="result"><button ng-click="cerrarModal()">Cerrar</button></div>',
      controller: "ContrladorModal"
    }).then(function(modal) {
      modal.close.then(function(result) {
        // Una vez que el modal sea cerrado, la libreria invoca esta función
        // y en result tienes el resultado.
        $scope.resultadoModal = result;
      });
    });

  };

});

app.controller('ContrladorModal', function($scope, close) {
  $scope.result = "Esta es la respuesta";
  $scope.cerrarModal = function() {
    close($scope.result);
  };

});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px; left: 50px; bottom: 50px; right: 50px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 100;
}
.overlay {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/master/dst/angular-modal-service.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <button ng-click="mostrarModal()">Ver Modal</button>
  <br>{{ resultadoModal }}
</div>
```

Comment: Le he echado un vistazo, tiene muy buena pinta y es muy similar al de ngDialog. Como comentas, este es mucho mas ligero que ngDIalog no incluyendo cosas como, la integración con HammerJs para proporcionar mejoras en el uso táctil, y otras que quizas no necesitas. Algo que si veo importante cuando elijo una librería es el nº de estrellas y de colaboradores, en eso la diferencia entre ambas es importante.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses el módulo [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) porque es sencillo de utilizar y muy potente en cuanto a funcionalidades, que permiten desde mostrar un texto plano, hasta mostrar una plantilla avanzada con su controlador.

La parte que mas de gusta de esta solución, con respecto a otras que he visto, es que está implementado como servicio (también está disponible una directiva) y que los resultados de obtienen con un *Promise*

En este [enlace](http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/) puedes ver una demo

Answer (score 0):

Yo me cree una directiva que permite abrir y cerrar el modal, que tiene el siguiente código:

```
app.directive("modalShow", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            modalVisible: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //Hide or show the modal
            scope.showModal = function (visible) {
                if (visible)
                {
                    element.modal("show");
                }
                else
                {
                    element.modal("hide");
                }
            }
            //Check to see if the modal-visible attribute exists
            if (!attrs.modalVisible)
            {
                //The attribute isn't defined, show the modal by default
                scope.showModal(true);
            }
            else
            {
                //Watch for changes to the modal-visible attribute
                scope.$watch("modalVisible", function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    scope.showModal(newValue);
                });

                //Update the visible value when the dialog is closed through UI actions (Ok, cancel, etc.)
                element.bind("hide.bs.modal", function () {
                    // scope.modalVisible = false;
                    _.defer(function(){scope.$apply(scope.modalVisible = false);});
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

El Codigo HTML quedaria asi:

```
<button ng-click='toggleModal()'></button>
       <div modal-show modal-visible="showDialogFavoriteSelect" class='modal fade'>
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
              <h3>My Modal</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Y para llamarlo desde cualquier controller solo usarias algo como esto:

```
$scope.toggleModal = function() {
  $scope.showDialogFavoriteSelect = true;
};
```

Lo que ocurre es que al pisar el botón, y se dispara la función de toggleModal, se cambia el valor de `showDialogFavoriteSelect` y se cambia el valor de `modalVisible` que tiene un `watch` y se muestra o oculta el modal.

No es necesario usar un botón con tan solo cambiar el valor de `showDialogFavoriteSelect` lo mostrara u ocultara.

**Nota**: Es necesario usar `bootstrap` para este enfoque.

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/X0u4gsaEFmib7SiKbVUp?p=preview)